# Liferay asset publisher entry variable assignment to itself in adt

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

I'm using Liferay 7 and by looking at the default adts for asset publisher I see, in the "Rich Summary" adt, the following portion of code

```
<#list entries as entry>
  <#assign
    entry = entry
    assetRenderer = entry.getAssetRenderer()
    entryTitle = htmlUtil.escape(assetRenderer.getTitle(locale))
    viewURL = assetPublisherHelper.getAssetViewURL(renderRequest, renderResponse, entry)
  />
  ...
```

(see it on GitHub https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/test/functional/com/liferay/portalweb/dependencies/adt_asset_publisher_rich_summary.ftl)

Is there any reason for doing the `entry = entry` assignment?

It seems to me like that shouldn't be necessary, am I maybe missing some reason why it might be necessary in freemarker such an assignment?

[edit]

Considering that this way `entry` will be defined even outside the `list` loop, why was this done? Is it necessary?

In this template there are actually no more references to this variable. So is this assignement needed while creating a new custom adt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the use of macros, outside the loop at the bottom of this file.

Answer (score 3):

As `#assign` creates/writes a variable in the namespace of the current template, while `#list` creates a variable in the scope of the loop (a more specific, narrower scope), that statement copies `entity` from the loop scope to the wider template namespace scope. If it's really needed in that template, I don't know; look for references to `entry` in that (or an `#include`/`#imported`-d) template that is outside the `#list`. It's not needed in the part quoted.